# How to Prove or disapprove the following proposition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Prove or disapprove:

Let ‎$‎f‎$‎ be a integral real function such that ‎$‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)‎$ ‎is ‎convergent‎. Then, ‎$‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{a}^{b} f(k+x)‎dx$ ‎is ‎convergent ‎for ‎every ‎‎$‎x\geq 0‎$‎.

Comment: It's wrong because $f$ can take almost arbirtrary values between natural numbers.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{a}^{b} f(k+x)‎dx$ does not depend on $x$ !! ?

Comment: To depend on $x$.

Comment: To depend on $x$.